# Different template for loading data and zero results

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to show loader text while the data is being retrieved and another text when the data is retrieved but there are zero results.

This is my current template:

```
<h3>Items</h3>
<ul>
  {{#each item in controllers.items}}
    <li>{{ title }}</li>
  {{else}}
    <li>No items found</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But now the text: `No items found` is also showed when the data is being retrieved.

Is something like the following template possible with Emberjs?

```
<h3>Items</h3>
<ul>
  {{#each item in controllers.items}}
    <li>{{ title }}</li>
  {{else if loading}}
    <li>Loading....</li>
  {{else}}
    <li>No items found</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: did you try like this `{{#each items}}` ..simple code in jsfiddle or jsbin would help to solve you issue...there is no `else if` currently...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible exactly your way, but i do it that way, that i am adding a loading flag to my controller, so that i can access it in the template:

```
<h3>Items</h3>
<ul>
  {{#if loading}} 
     I am loading your items!
  {{else}}
    {{#each item in controllers.items}}
      <li>{{ title }}</li>
    {{else}}
      <li>No items found</li>
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
</ul>
```

So your Controller could look like this using a timeout approach to reset the loading flag:

```
App.YourController = Ember.ArrayController({
  loading : false, // set this property, when you are loading new content into the controller
  resetLoadingObserver : function(){
     // this gets triggered on each modification to the array
     // we want to reset the loading property, once all new items have been added
     var that = this;
     $.doTimeout("resetLoadingFlag", 100, function(){
       that.set("loading", false)
     });
  }.observes("content.@each")
});
```

Comment: This is just a possible implementation. I myself am using a View to load more items upon scrolling, which resets the loading property.